# Using mysql, calculate the UNIX time difference between to rows

Tags: mysql

[image]

In this table, there are 100 different receipt_ids. Each receipt_id has multiple statuses. I want to calculate the time difference between the status_code DWRESULT_INIT and DWRESULT_SAVED. I want to group the results by receipt_id so I can see the time difference for all 100 receipt_ids in the DB. I am new to mysql, and am not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: Write one query to get all the `DWRESULT_INIT` rows. Write another query to get all the `DWRESULT_SAVED` rows. Join the two subqueries on the `receipt_id` column, and subtract the timestamps.

Comment: so , one receipt has only one DWRESULT_INIT and DWRESULT_SAVED?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mysql's [timestampdiff()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function to calculate the difference and use `from_unixtime()` function to convert the timestamp into a datetime data type. To get the 2 status codes into a single record, use a subquery to get the init records only and join it back to your table filtered saved:

```
select t1.receipt_id, timestampdiff(second, from_unixtime(t2.event_time), from_unixtime(t1.event_time)) as diff
from yourtable t1
inner join
    (select receipt_id, event_time
     from yourtable
     where status_code='DWRESULT_INIT') t2 on t1.receipt_id=t2.receipt_id
where t1.status_code='DWRESULT_SAVED'
```

Comment: Thanks , I deleted my answer +1

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting NULL as the diff, but its probably a typo on my end.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
SELECT 
T1.type,
if(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, FROM_UNIXTIME(T1.start_time),FROM_UNIXTIME(T1.end_time)) IS NULL,0,TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, FROM_UNIXTIME(T1.start_time),FROM_UNIXTIME(T1.end_time))) AS totalTimeInMinute,
T1.start_time AS startTime,
T1.end_time AS endTime
FROM (SELECT type,createdAt AS start_time,(SELECT createdAt FROM Worktime WHERE date='2020-10-08' AND createdAt > start_time LIMIT 1) AS end_time FROM Worktime 
WHERE date='2020-10-08') AS T1
```

> 

[image]